# Typescript converting an array of objects to a Map

Tags: typescript

I have the following array:

```
const myArray = [{
   a: 'test',
   b: 1
}, {
   a: 'test1',
   b: 2
}];
```

I would like to convert this array to a Map, based on one of it's properties, and maintain a strongly typed code, with a function like this:

```
convertArrayToMap<TObject extends {}, TArray extends TObject[], TProperty extends keyof TObject>(inputArray: TArray, property: TProperty): Map<TProperty, TObject> {
   // ... logic goes here <-- I AM AWARE of the logical code, this is not what I need, I need help in typing my function
}
```

I am having two troubles with the typings here:

1. when I try to use the function, typescript implies `TProperty` as never, yet it correctly identifies the `TArray` type. Why is this happening?
2. the way how this is written at the moment, the returned `Map` is set to have keys of the `TProperty` value, but instead of that, I would need keys typed as the type of the `TProperty` from the object. I tried with `typeof TProperty` but typescript complains.

In general, here is an example, on how the function should work:

```
const map = convertArrayToMap(myArray, 'a'); // this should be a Map<string, { a: string, b: number}> type 
console.log(map.get('test').b); // this logs 1 on the screen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
function convertArrayToMap<
  TObject extends object,
  TProperty extends keyof TObject,
>(
  inputArray: TObject[],
  property: TProperty,
): Map<TObject[TProperty], TObject> {
  // ...
}
```

Here's also [a link to playground](https://tsplay.dev/mLRzkw).

Comment: yes, this solves part of my problem, but, my Map now states that it is a `Map<'a', { a: string, b: number}>` instead of it being a `Map<string, { a: string, b: number}>`, so that still remains. :( (based on the example in the original question)

Comment: Isn't `Map<'a', ...>` better for your needs than `Map<string, ...>`?

Comment: I can change this, I'm just asking

Comment: Oh, right, I misunderstood the question. You want a _value_ of the property to be the key. Got it, on it

Comment: doesn't `Map<'a', ...>` mean that it is a map that has a single `a` key?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in infering the literal type, you can consider thsis example:

```js
export { }; // ignore this

type Overloading<
  Tuple extends any[],
  Prop extends keyof Tuple[number],
  Result extends Map<never, never> = Map<never, never>
  > =
  Tuple extends []
  ? Result
  : Tuple extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
  ? Prop extends keyof Head ? Overloading<Tail, Prop, Result & Map<Head[Prop], Head>> : never : never

declare function convertArrayToMap<
  Key extends PropertyKey,
  Value extends string | number,
  Obj extends Record<Key, Value>,
  Prop extends keyof Obj,
  Tuple extends Obj[]
>(
  tuple: [...Tuple],
  property: Prop,
): Overloading<[...Tuple],Prop>;


const map = convertArrayToMap([
  {
    id: "123",
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 42,
  },
  {
    id: "456",
    name: "Jane Doe",
    age: 17,
  },
], 'id');

// {
//     id: "123";
//     name: "John Doe";
//     age: 42;
// }
const person = map.get("123"); // this is `{id: 123, name:'JohnDoe'} | undefined`
const name = person!.name; "John Doe"
```

[PLayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwNxwPQbgSwOYB20wcMAFjgM4BQ1MAnmCQPIBuwUANhAIYAmOAngA81OHAAqAVzCcSoGMAJ9KcHgXoBtALoAaMXAAKUCGDgKlKuAGtg9CADNJMuZoJSAtgCMOegwCVgSilOeAtlVQBZHjBhAmB2KF04eMSAPjgAXjho2NSOZPyoNIMMzINpWXkQRQi4HQMAfjhA4NCDAC5nKvMay1VNQQcOOAAJYH5kgDoZoZGJHhxObSajEzNwq1t7J3H%20OGa2Dm5%20QREFpeTjU2TWkPgAMhyY4T2%20TWuwPTGJvjSMrpFOCAhIcWh8YAAY04PCgJAcUgIkJgOAgBDgkLRiRgAEEoFAePQJBBcqJxABpOy9WpWT4cBiU%20j6cQANR4nCk1RpqkoMCgZzgAB8Up4fEkDMwvAAran9FpQ6B8YSM5JsjnANLMtamWV1baOOCSqVaypyXVWI0NNIACgMMBcwC6mhmU1NwD84jA63p9C6n30AEoukcuLwBEJhM6Zm69J80qhaNRMQReXAPDEshisfS8QSiSSYtbNAYEAZxDg%20F0AEQARgATABmKta8QEHgeR1wKsAKQgZHRABEIMBm2W1HhOwAWOta5Ba0vicuVruTgCsADZR4uUu3Oz31CQhyOW%20POzWAOyz-TfADkFZvAYT1CwiGf2G3Fer9abCZf27bHbVr2-ZwEeVa-u%20i48BOXTThBKBJmiqZMFAlBopm6ZgFME4wNataNlWj6YNg5BULgqgAAaGBwaHosKiIQg4gjAHwFGISm8AASQ2QobRACEUxcegPZ9oOw5VtQQA)

**`Overloading`** iterates through provided tuple, and creates an overloading of `Map` data structure for appropriate key.

Drawback: it works only with literal argument or with `as const` assertion.

More about inference on function arguments you can find in my [blog](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

Keep in mind, that intersection of `Map<string, number> & Map<number,string>` creates an overloading:

```js
type Overloading = Map<string, number> & Map<number,string>;

declare const map: Overloading;

map.get('hello') // number | undefined
map.get(42) // string | undefined
```